# `dplyr::full_join()` doesn't work with list columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidy

I am trying to compare formals for two versions of a given function in R package `ggstatsplot`. I have been able to extract formals in tibbles but I can't seem to get these two tables to join. `dplyr::full_join()` produces an error but it is not really clear what it entails. Would appreciate any feedback on how I can join these two dataframes.

```r
# setup
set.seed(123)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggstatsplot)

# formals for the primary version of the function
(df_primary <- tibble::enframe(formals(ggstatsplot::gghistostats)) %>%
  dplyr::rename(.data = ., primary = value))
#> # A tibble: 41 x 2
#>    name        primary  
#>    <chr>       <list>   
#>  1 data        <NULL>   
#>  2 x           <missing>
#>  3 binwidth    <NULL>   
#>  4 bar.measure <chr [1]>
#>  5 xlab        <NULL>   
#>  6 title       <NULL>   
#>  7 subtitle    <NULL>   
#>  8 caption     <NULL>   
#>  9 type        <chr [1]>
#> 10 test.value  <dbl [1]>
#> # ... with 31 more rows

# formals for the grouped version of the function
(df_grouped <- tibble::enframe(formals(ggstatsplot::grouped_gghistostats)) %>%
  dplyr::rename(.data = ., grouped = value))
#> # A tibble: 43 x 2
#>    name         grouped  
#>    <chr>        <list>   
#>  1 data         <missing>
#>  2 x            <missing>
#>  3 grouping.var <missing>
#>  4 title.prefix <NULL>   
#>  5 binwidth     <NULL>   
#>  6 bar.measure  <chr [1]>
#>  7 xlab         <NULL>   
#>  8 subtitle     <NULL>   
#>  9 caption      <NULL>   
#> 10 type         <chr [1]>
#> # ... with 33 more rows

# joining the two dataframes name
dplyr::full_join(
  x = df_primary,
  y = df_grouped,
  by = "name"
)
#> Error: type not supported

traceback()
#> 4: stop(list(message = "type not supported", call = NULL, cppstack = NULL))
#> 3: full_join_impl(x, y, by_x, by_y, aux_x, aux_y, na_matches, environment())
#> 2: full_join.tbl_df(x = tibble::enframe(formals(ggstatsplot::gghistostats)) %>% 
#> dplyr::rename(.data = ., primary = value), y = tibble::enframe(formals(ggstatsplot::grouped_gghistostats)) %>% 
#> dplyr::rename(.data = ., grouped = value), by = "name")
#> 1: dplyr::full_join(x = tibble::enframe(formals(ggstatsplot::gghistostats)) %>% 
#> dplyr::rename(.data = ., primary = value), y = tibble::enframe(formals(ggstatsplot::grouped_gghistostats)) %>% 
#> dplyr::rename(.data = ., grouped = value), by = "name")
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the `dotted paired` type is not supported.  One thing, we could do it to convert it to a normal `list` and then do the `full_join`

```
formals(ggstatsplot::gghistostats) %>% 
     as.list %>% 
     tibble::enframe(value = 'primary') %>% 
     full_join(formals(ggstatsplot::grouped_gghistostats) %>% 
                 as.list %>% 
                 tibble::enframe(value = 'grouped'))
# A tibble: 40 x 3
#   name        primary   grouped  
#   <chr>       <list>    <list>   
# 1 data        <NULL>    <missing>
# 2 x           <missing> <missing>
# 3 binwidth    <NULL>    <NULL>   
# 4 bar.measure <chr [1]> <chr [1]>
# 5 xlab        <NULL>    <NULL>   
# 6 title       <NULL>    <NULL>   
# 7 subtitle    <NULL>    <NULL>   
# 8 caption     <NULL>    <NULL>   
# 9 type        <chr [1]> <chr [1]>
#10 test.value  <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]>
# … with 30 more rows
```

Comment: What is `dotted paired`?

Comment: @IndrajeetPatil. It is a type created from the `formals` i.e .`formals(lm) %>% str#
Dotted pair list of 14`